# How to declare layout to automatically adjust height of ListView in multiple devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to layout buttons in buttom of device.

Following pic1 is layout on 4.0 inch device, pic2 is on 4.7 inch device

and there is tried xml code.

buttons arranged correct position on 4.0 inch, 
but not on 4.7inch.

I'd like to automatically adjust height of List View.

How to do that?

[pic1]

[image]

[pic2]

[image]

Here is xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLabel2"
            android:text="Buyed items"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lsv_buyedList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="450dp">
    </ListView>


    <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sortById"
                    android:text="SortById"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sortByGrade"
                    android:text="SortByGrade"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
                android:text="OK"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Remove the hardcoded value from your listview `android:layout_height="450dp"`

and use weight for you listview

```
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lsv_buyedList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>
```

Comment: The accepted answer lacks the advise to not use the LinearLayout as you do. Please use a RelativeLayout. Then you are able to come up with the same result in absence of the 2 LinearLayouts used for the Button section. Note that each additional Layout forces one rendering cycle. What you do here isn't performant at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "weight" field for the ListView

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace  `android:layout_height="450dp"` with `android:layout_height="wrap_conent"` from listView

Answer (score 0):

copy this code and paste it.. It works i tried on my machine... enjoy..!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Buyed items"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lsv_buyedList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sortById"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SortById"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sortByGrade"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SortByGrade"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```